# Instancing in HLSL fragment shader

Tags: shader, directx-11, fragment-shader

I am using instancing in directx/hlsl to render two meshes from two views onto two different render targets. I have two view projection matrices which I am indexing using the InstanceId in the vertex shader. I see the VS Out in RenderDoc and it seems like the meshes are transformed correctly from the vertex shader. I am using the InstanceId in fragment shader to write some data to the corresponding render target in the following manner.

```
void MainPS(FTriangleIDPassGSToPS Input,
        out uint OutColor1 : SV_Target0,
        uint InstanceId : SV_InstanceID,
        out uint OutColor2 : SV_Target1)
{
    if(InstanceId)
    {
        OutColor2 = 10;
    }
    else
    {
        OutColor1 = 100;
    }
}
```

But when I visualize the two render targets in RenderDoc, I find that all the meshes have the same transformation. Although the values are different (RT 1 has values of 100 and RT 2 has values of 100), but I was expecting the meshes would be transformed according to the MVP used for that instance. In my case, both the meshes appear to have been viewed from the same viewpoint. Am I missing something ? I'm new to shader programming, so I might be doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing 2 concepts here, one thing is instancing that occurs in vertex shader and is able to apply different vertex attributes to each instancing. Another thing is multiple render targets, that happens in the output of a pixel shader, and is used to write different values for every target in a render to texture, but the rasterization of vertices into pixels are the same for every target, so you will get the same pixels in every target, but possibly with different color/values. This is typically used in deferred rendering to output surface info like normals, texture coords, etc

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So is there a workaround to get this to work ? As in drawing two instances of a mesh with two MVPs to two render targets ?

Comment: You have to render the meshes using one camera in a render target and after that render again the same meshes with the other camera in different render target.